# Store Icons in Program c#

Tags: c#, icons

I am trying to make a program that when clicked, allows a user to pick a random icon and build their own program with that icon.

It has options:

1. They can open their program files and get an icon
2. They can pick from a DEFAULT icon library that I have created.

I already created the option for #1, but how would I go about creating the option for #2?

I already have a few icons.

Comment: Are you asking where to store the default icons? Please be more specific what is the challenge in implementing option #2.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the question title, I will relate to only where you can store the icons and how you can use it in the code.

In the Solution Explorer, double click on the `Resources.resx` file. In the resources designer window you should click "Add Resource" and then you can see the option "Add Existing resource". Assuming one the files you added name is `icon1` and the resx file name is `Resources` and you have PictureBox instance called `pictureBox1` then this is how you can use the icon:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.icon1.ToBitmap();
```